# Why can't I buy Breezehome?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found the steward, but when I talked to him, it did not have the option to buy the house. Why is this? Do I have to do some sort of quest or something? I have already killed the bandit(s) but what else do I need to do? I have enough money.

Answer (score 5):

Once you acquire the Dragonstone, you can purchase Breezehome for 5000 gold from Proventus Avenicci. You acquire this item during the ["Bleak Falls Barrow" quest](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bleak_Falls_Barrow_(Quest)), which can be acquired from Farengar Secret-Fire once you talk to the Jarl of Whiterun.

You can also purchase this house from Brill if you have completed the ["Battle for Whiterun"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_for_Whiterun_(Stormcloaks)), siding with the Stormcloaks.

Comment: thx so much!!!I appreciate the help.

Comment: You have to have become the thane of whiterun before you can proceed in the civil war quest line

Comment: @anonymous Since this answered the question, there is a gray check on the left of the answer which you can click. It will turn green and the answer will be marked as accepted.